# c++, eclipse, field could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm implementing template binary tree in cpp with eclipse and I have trouble.

```
template <class T> struct node{
    T data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *rigth;
};
template<class T> node* newnode(T d) {
    struct node *ret = new(struct node());
    ret->left = NULL; //err here
    ret->right = NULL;//err here
    ret->data = d; //err here
    return ret;
}
```

I'm getting error "Field 'left' couldn't be resolved.". What's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
template <class T> struct node {
    T data;
    struct node<T> *left;
    struct node<T> *rigth;
};

template<class T> node<T>* newnode(T d) {
    struct node<T> *ret = new struct node<T>();
    ret->left = NULL;
    ret->right = NULL;
    ret->data = d;
    return ret;
}
```