# Field not resolved for node in Linked list

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, nodes

I am getting a "Field not resolved error" with this line of code:

```
template <class Object>
void FHlist<Object>::pop_back()
{
   Node *p;

   // safer, but a little slower with this test
   if ( mSize == 0 )
      return;

   p = mTail->prev;
   mTail->prev = p->prev;  // ERROR IS HERE
   mTail->prev->next = mTail;
   delete p;
   mSize--;
}
```

This is my Node class declaration:

```
template <class Object>
class FHlist<Object>::Node
{
public: 
   Node *prev, *next;
   Object data;

   Node( const Object & d = Object(), Node *prv = NULL, Node *nxt = NULL )
      : prev(prv), next(nxt), data(d)
   { }
};
```

Why am i getting this error and how would i resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to change the code as follows:

```
template <class Object>
class FHlist<Object>::Node
{
    public: 
       Node<Object> *prev, *next;
};
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141900/c-eclipse-field-could-not-be-resolved)

Answer (score 1):

Also You might want to revisit your pop_back fn,

```
   p = mTail;
   mTail = p->prev;
   mTail->next = NULL;
   delete p;
```

Comment: This code deletes the last node from the linked list(assuming mTail is the pointer to the last node) which I believe is the correct way. The logic in the question is deleting the second last node from the linked list(not sure if this is done on a purpose).

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in previous line.
What is mTail?
-edit- how do I add it as a comment?

Comment: it is a node that was created earlier. it points to the tail of the linked list

Comment: Srry did not see your reply earlier. I'm assuming the by now you would have the issue figured out by yourself.
The error you are getting because of the type of p and mTail. p is  pointers of type Node and it does not have members names prev,next. You have these two members for the class you derived from Node.